# How to add a border to a surface?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, famo.us

This is my code
I'm trying to add a border to a surface, i've tried many variations what am i doing wrong?
This is just a red bar, I want any kind of border on it, but this proves to be difficult, what's going on?

```
var surface = new Surface({
    size: [window.innerWidth/2, 10],
    border: [10],
    properties: { 
        background: 'red',
        border:10,
        borderColor:'blue'}

});

var sizeModifier = new Modifier({
    size: [window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight]
});

var alignModifier = new Modifier({
    align: [0.5, 0.5],
    origin:[0.5, 0.5]
});

mainContext.add(sizeModifier).add(alignModifier).add(surface);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that your surface has a too small height to draw a 10px border. You should also add a line style to the border e.g. solid. You could try the following to see a border:

```
var surface = new Surface({
    content: '<h1>Famous in JSFiddle</h1>',
    size: [window.innerWidth / 2, 100],
    border: [10],
    properties: {
        background: 'red',
        border: '10px solid',
        borderColor: 'blue'
    }
});
```

```js
Famous.loaded(function () {
    var Engine = Famous.Core.Engine;
    var Modifier = Famous.Core.Modifier;
    var RenderNode = Famous.Core.RenderNode;
    var Surface = Famous.Core.Surface;
    var Transform = Famous.Core.Transform;

    var mainContext = Engine.createContext();
    
    var surface = new Surface({
        content: '<h1>Famous in JSFiddle</h1>',
        size: [window.innerWidth / 2, 100],
        border: [10],
        properties: {
            background: 'red',
            border: '10px solid',
            borderColor: 'blue'
        }
    });

    var sizeModifier = new Modifier({
        size: [window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight]
    });

    var alignModifier = new Modifier({
        align: [0.5, 0.5],
        origin: [0.5, 0.5]
    });

    mainContext.add(sizeModifier).add(alignModifier).add(surface);

    
    /*
    var surface = new Surface({
        content: '<h1>Famous in JSFiddle</h1>'
    });

    var modifier = new Modifier({
        transform: Transform.translate(50, 50)
    });
    */

    //var node = new RenderNode(modifier);
    //node.add(surface);

    var appContext = mainContext; //Engine.createContext();
    //appContext.add(node);

    Engine.pipe(Application);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://rawgit.com/jperl/famous-compiled/97f85aaa64af255adfe0407c941e0e859b0759bc/dist/src/804b0adb.main.js"></script>
<script src="http://rawgit.com/jperl/famous-compiled/e9c12b1fa657820d3f9bad093ea72e8ee2dfec46/dist/src/4f231991.polyfills.js"></script>
<link href="https://rawgit.com/jperl/famous-compiled/e9c12b1fa657820d3f9bad093ea72e8ee2dfec46/dist/lib/famous/core/famous.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
```

Comment: cool thanks, is it known that famo.us will have ALL the css style-options in camelcase?

Comment: yes, that's right as they write it in their guide [here](http://famo.us/university/lessons/#/famous-101/displaying/4).